# Zabbix Userparameter Empty Value Trigger

Tags: zabbix, zabbix-agent

Could someone help me to fire a trigger when an item is receiving an empty value from zabbix-agent?
By using item string type I can use strlen function, but what about integer type?

What is the recommended way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Zabbix doesn't support empty values for the integer type.